# Extract value from string in flutter(dart)

Tags: string, flutter, dart, mobile-development

I have a string that is formatted like this:

ABC: title="EXAMPLE-TITLE", url="null", raw.length="28"

is there a way to always extract only the "title" field ?
I would not want to use substring.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to do some kind of parsing, maybe use a map to store your title, url and access it like that.